# Truncate a string after match a specific word in smarty or javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, smarty

I am working on a website but somehow I have sometimes little bug coming from the add of content after the end of some string.

For example :
`style="background-image:url({$sub.image});"` return
 `style="background-image:url(http://blablalba.fr/phoenix.jpg%3Fv%3D1);"`

As you can see there is **%3Fv%3D1** after the end on the link (after .jpg). I don't know where this is coming from and I'd like to erase it.

So my question is : in smarty is there a way to truncate a String after matching a word ?

And if it is not possible, what is the easiest way in Js/jQuery ?

I tough of this Regex to match the correct string : `/^(.*?\.jpg)/`

So it lead me to this :

```
$('.append').each('li',function(){
   var newLink = $(this).find('div').css('background-image').match(/^(.*?\.jpg)/);
   $(this).find('div').css('background-image',newLink);
})
```

But this is still buggy so if someone as a better idea of how shall I do this ?

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n62djktu/1/) if it can provide some help.

### Edit + Answer

Ok so as has said @Hitmands just below it was a problem of URI encoding. 
So this is the clearest and smartest solution :

```
$('.imgLittle').each(function() {
    newLink = decodeURIComponent($(this).css('background-image'));
    $(this).css('background-image',newLink)
})
```

And here is the final (working) [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n62djktu/7/).

Hope this could help someone once.

Comment: Use `replace` , `$(this).find('div').css('background-image').replace(/^(.*?\.jpg).*/, "$1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to exec this `window.decodeURIComponent("%3Fv%3D1")` in your console it returns a simply **"?v=1"**, this could be a way to manage the client-caching... when the *v* (version?) param changes it forces the browser to download the resource even is already cached...

I think that this is an important information that you cannot strip!

A smart solution could be a simply decoding of this param.... you should, but I'm not sure, try http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl...

If isn't possible to decode the URI Component via smarty, you can do it via Javascript using the code that you posted below with the window.decodeURIComponent instead of regex-stripping.

Comment: This was really well tough pretty nice answer I share the solution in my post!